# AccessViolationException error in passing float value from C# to C dll using CLI

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c, dll

I call a function from C dll from my C# application. The error is AccessViolationException. My C dll is:

**cinterface.h**

```
#ifdef ACQ_EXPORTS
#define ACQ_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define ACQ_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" {
    #endif
    ACQ_API int set_integration_time(float int_time);
    #ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Then my CLI class is:

```
#include "cinterface.h"       
public ref class Class1 {
    private:            
        float int_time;
        float wait_time;
    public:
        Class1(){}
        ~Class1(){}

        int Class1::set_integratintime(double int_t) {
            int_time = (float)int_t;
            set_integration_time(int_time); 
            return PASS;
        }
};
```

That CLI class wraps the C function from the dll. This CLI is implemented as dll and that Class1 CLI dll is ported into my C# application project. My C# application is as follow

Then my C# application:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        Class1 cameraInt = new Class1();
    }

    private void wait_time_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        int ret = cameraInt.set_integratintime(100);
    }
}
```

When I debug I got error at CLI class at the line;

```
set_integration_time(int_time);
```

The error is:

> AccessViolationException was unhandled
>   Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication 
>    that other memory is corrupt.

What is wrong with the interface?

**EDIT:**
When I interface the C dll function `int set_integration_time(float int_time);` from a C application, it works. That means C function inside the dll is fine. Just that access from CLI have an issue.

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the interface.  There's something wrong with the way you debug it.  You *must* enable unmanaged debugging and set a breakpoint on the C function.  Now you'll have a shot at diagnosing why it fails.

Comment: Since I don't have access to C dll, that is third party dll. The last place I can put break point is at set_integration_time(int_time); inside CLI code. I set the break point there and the error is AccessViolationException.

Comment: Now solved the problem, interface using CLI has no issue. So using CLI to interface from C# to C dll is quite straigth forward. The issue is at a camera object inside the dll, I need to call open/call interfaces before/after I access other interfaces.